# What does $[0, B]^n$ mean?

Tags: notation

What does $[0, B]^n$ mean here $f : [0, B]^n \rightarrow [0, B]$

I know that it is the domain of $f$, and that the range of $f$ is $[0, B]$. But how to interpret the exponent $n$ of the domain?

Answer (score 2):

It means$$\overbrace{[0,B]\times[0,B]\times\cdots\times[0,B]}^{\phantom{\text{ times}}N\text{ times}}.$$

Answer (score 2):

The Cartesian product of $[0,B]$ with itself n times. That is, the set of ordered $n$-tuples $(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)$ where $0\leq x_i \leq B$ for $i=1,\ldots, n$.

Answer (score 0):

The line segment between $[0,B]$ taken $n$ times, i.e. for $n$ different real numbers.

A subset of $\mathbb R^n$ where each real number is between $[0,B]$.

So a function takes $n$ real numbers in (each between $0$ and $B$) and gives one value between $0$ and $B$ out.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA you are correct, the real definition of power set is indeed much more unintuitive. For me the word power relates to multiplication more than to splitting up and taking all possible parts of something.